# Find and Replace " [[ mytext]]" Using Bash shell SED

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to replace String in `[[ Mystring ]]` data to `MyData`.

```
pattern='[[ Mystring ]]'
replacement='MyData'
sed -i 's/pattern/replacement/g' Myfile.txt
```

What is wrong with above code? How to search data inside `[[]]`?

Comment: Take a look at https://regex101.com/.  You need double quotes for the `sed` command.

Comment: Do you want `[[ Mystring ]]` -> `MyData`, or do you want `[[ Mystring ]]` -> `[[ MyData ]]`?

Answer (score 2):

It should be like:

```
pattern='\[\[ Mystring \]\]'
replacement='MyData'
sed -i "s/$pattern/$replacement/g" Myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the `[`

```
sed -i 's/\[\[\s*Mystring\s*\]\]/foo/g' text.txt
```